Power Apps command visibility based on user security role
Using power apps command editor. How to check the user security roles before displaying a button in the command bar.
This command is displayed on a page inside Dynamics 365 sales.
Here is my formula:
!IsBlank(Self.Selected.Item.'FieldX') && 
!IsBlank(Self.Selected.Item.'FieldY') && 
!Self.Selected.Item.AlreadyDone &&
/* Some code to check that the user has security role 'X' */

Is there a way to verify the user security rôle in a Visibility Formula?
I tried to use the User function and also tried other functions such as UserRoles and Roles but there is no function with those names that seems to be defined.

I was missing a few parts. First I had to open the command in the Components Library when editing the commands in Power Automate.

Then I had to add two connections. The 'Users' and 'Security Roles'.
Since my command is in a solution, I also had to add to add those two tables in the solution.

After that, I could query the tables in the formula text box. I came up with something like this:
!IsBlank(LookUp(LookUp('Rôles de sécurité', Nom="X").Utilisateurs,'Nom d''utilisateur'=User().Email).'Nom d''utilisateur')


PS. Sorry, the Power Automate I used is in French. If you encounter this problem you can figure the tables and properties names yourself.


if you can filter based on an Azure Security Group, you can use this formula:
If(User().Email in Office365Groups.ListGroupMembers("...", {'$top':999}).value.mail, 
...,...)


Thank you for your answer, it helps me figure out how to do it using Power Automate Security Group.
